# SQL Query to find list of values from rows in a table 'B' contained in groups of a table 'A'

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, relational-division

```
create table A {
   id   text,
   val  text }

create table B {
   val0 text, 
   val1 text,
   val2 text }
```

`id` and `val` of table `A` contain each a large, but discrete number of values in an many-to-many relationship. Sample data looks like follows:

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| one | a |
| one | b |
| one | y |
| two | a |
| two | d |
| two | e |
| two | x |
| three | c |
| four | c |
| four | f |
| four | z |
| four | g |

The second table `B` contains combinations from the same set as those for `val`, for example:

| val0 | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| a | d | e |
| c | f | g |
| z | f | c |

I am trying to find a query that returns those, and only those, `id`'s of table `A` for which there are `val` that cover at least one entire row from table `B`.

In the example above, the query should return `id` "two", because that id-group contains all values from the second row in table `B`, i.e. "a", "d", and "e". It is irrelevant that "x" is contained in that group as well. The query also should return "four", as the values in that group cover now rows 3 and 4 in table `B`. The order in table `A` or table `B` is not important.

I managed to do the query as a procedure. What is a concise SQL query that works efficiently with tables with millions of rows?

Post scriptum:
Both answers provided by @Ajax1234 and @GMB (second answer that does not introduce a pk) work well. However, the left-join based solution by @Ajax1234 was significantly more performant on the real dataset: it took about 9 seconds for @Ajax1234 solution vs. more than a minute for the solution by @GMB

Comment: Please update your question to provide the code you have tried and your challenge with that so we may best assist you here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The challenge is not with code of the procedure, but the fact that I coudn't figure out how it needs to be implemented as a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a series of `left join`s:

```
select distinct a.id 
from B b 
left join A a on b.val0 = a.val 
left join A a1 on b.val1 = a1.val and a.id = a1.id 
left join A a2 on b.val2 = a2.val and a2.id = a.id 
where a.id is not null and a1.id is not null and a2.id is not null
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NCC_P2CO).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a relation division approach here.

Normally you would have a primary key in the second table, say `pk`, so we could do:

```
select a.id, b.pk
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on a.val in (b.val0, b.val1, b.val2)
group by a.id, b.pk 
having count(*) = 3
```

Note that this assumes no duplicates id/val tuples in the first table, otherwise we need `count(distinct a.val)` instead.

An alternative is a lateral join (which also does not require a pk in the second table):

```
select b.*, a.id
from tableb b
cross join lateral (
    select a.id
    from tablea a 
    where a.val in (b.val0, b.val1, b.val2)
    group by a.id
    having count(*) = 3
) a
```